# What does "|" means outside a set?

Tags: notation

So I have a problem so solve that asks me to solve if 17|m is valid for an equation; and another to solve for "if a|b and a|c then a|(b+c)".

I know that "|" stands for set values inside a set (such as {x|x>3}), but those examples are about proof-writing.

What does "|" mean in those cases?

Comment: $a|b$ means $a$ divides $b$

Comment: $a\mid b$ means "$a$ is a divisor of $b$," which means there is some integer $d$ such that $ad=b$. So, for example, $2\mid 6$ but $4\not\mid 6$.

Comment: Oh, I see. I guess that it does fit in.

Comment: It's not really related to the set theory notation at all.